# 3rd opac background doesn't work (multiple backgrounds with opacity in CSS3)

Tags: css

I couldn't understand why my 3rd background doesn't work?

what I tried is here: http://jsbin.com/yopodusu/1/edit , `#page::after` background doesn't work.

```
body {
    line-height: 1;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: transparent url(http://i.imgur.com/SwFFw1i.gif) repeat top left;
}
body::after {
    content: "";
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/QOSseW6.jpg);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -2;
    opacity: .150;
}
#page::after {
    content: "";
    background: url(http://www.zordor.com/w/1920x1200/6098.jpg) no-repeat right top;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: .150;
    background-size: 35%;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

regards

Comment: Did you remember to add `position:relative` to `#page`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got this property overriding the element's visibility :

```
.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after { 
    content:"\0020"; 
    display:block; 
    height:0; 
    visibility:hidden;  
}
```

Add `visibility : visible` to your `#page:after`

And `height : auto` as well, or setup a specific height.

Which gives :

```
#page::after {
    content: "";
    background: url(http://www.zordor.com/w/1920x1200/6098.jpg) no-repeat right top;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: .150;
    background-size: 35%;
    visibility : visible;
    height: auto;
}
```